# How to Link to Other XML Object Within Document

Tags: xml

I am wondering how I can prevent copying and pasting repeated xml code by simply referencing one master object.

For example, given the master object:

```
<node id="master">
  <info>information1</info>
</node>
```

I want to be able to essentially insert that code many times throughout my XML document

```
<nodes>
  insert master node here

  insert master node here
</nodes>
```

Comment: Not entirely clear, but probably you should use XLink/XPointer.

Comment: What isn't clear @AlexanderPetrov?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, It can be done as follows. For more information, see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_entities.asp.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE xml [ <!ENTITY myentity "
<node>
  <info>information1</info>
</node>
" > ]>


<nodes>
&myentity;

&myentity;
</nodes>
```